# Maven Including test Scoped Transitive Dependencies in WAR

Tags: java, maven

Maven 3.0.5 and Maven 3.2.1

I have a Maven project which is a test library aggregation with the intent that if you depend on that project with a scope of "test" that you can have all of the testing libraries you need.

The issue I am having is that a dependency of one of the included testing libraries is getting included in the WAR of the web project.

The test library aggregation project:

```
<project ...>
    <groupId>com.group</groupId>
    <artifactId>test-lib</artifactId>
    <name>test-lib</name>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.easymock</groupId>
            <artifactId>easymock</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.directory.server</groupId>
            <artifactId>apacheds-test-framework</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-M19</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

The web project:

```
<project ...>
    <groupId>com.group</groupId>
    <artifactId>web-project</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>web-project</name>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.group</groupId>
            <artifactId>test-lib</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

In the web project I am depending on test-lib with a scope of "test". When I look at the dependency hierarchy, all the sub-dependencies of test-lib correctly have a scope of "test".

apacheds-test-framework depends on commons-io 2.4 and commons-fileupload depends on commons-io 1.1.

What I am expecting to happen is that commons-io 2.4 is used only for testing and when the WAR is built, only common-io 1.1 is included in the archive. But what is actually happening is that commons-io 2.4 AND commons-io 1.1 are included in the WAR.

[image]

I cannot simply exclude commons-io from test-lib in web-project because test-lib needs 2.4, I cannot upgrade the version of commons-fileupload at this time, and I cannot allow both JARs to be packaged in the WAR.

This seems to be a bug in the way Maven handles trasitive dependencies in some cases. This is not the first time I have had Maven not trasitively test-scope dependencies of test-scoped dependencies. I am at a loss for what to do here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked this on command line via `mvn dependency:tree` furthermore have you checked the resulting war file which should be created on command line via `mvn clean package` ? If you think this is a bug please report it on the user mailing list or much more better create a jira issue for that and please include a complete example which produces this behaviour.

Comment: Are you sure that `commons-io-2.4` is not pulled as a transitive dependency of another dependency? Can you post the result of `mvn dependency:tree`?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cleaned my workspace, then the behavior stopped and again I only had 1.1 in the WAR. But, definitely io 2.4 was getting pulled in as a transitive dependency because I could see its source in the dependency hierarchy in Eclipse. And the source was Apache DS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strangely, after cleaning my workspace. The problem stopped and I only had commons-io 1.1 in the WAR.

Answer (score 0):

So i have [created an example based](https://github.com/khmarbaise/so-questions/tree/master/so-2) on your question with exactly the dependencies you have given. If i build the project via `mvn clean package`(Maven 3.2.5):

So if i check the contents of the created war file i got the following:

```
$ unzip -t web/target/web-1.0.8-SNAPSHOT.war
Archive:  web/target/web-1.0.8-SNAPSHOT.war
    testing: META-INF/                OK
    testing: META-INF/MANIFEST.MF     OK
    testing: WEB-INF/                 OK
    testing: WEB-INF/classes/         OK
    testing: WEB-INF/lib/             OK
    testing: WEB-INF/lib/commons-fileupload-1.1.1.jar   OK
    testing: WEB-INF/lib/commons-io-1.1.jar   OK
    testing: WEB-INF/web.xml          OK
    testing: META-INF/maven/com.soebes.examples.so/web/pom.xml   OK
    testing: META-INF/maven/com.soebes.examples.so/web/pom.properties   OK
    testing: META-INF/INDEX.LIST      OK
No errors detected in compressed data of web/target/web-1.0.8-SNAPSHOT.war.
```

which is exactly what i expected to see.

This brings me to the conclusion that in your case there must be some other dependencies involved. Can you reduce your project to a working example? So we are able to drill down to the root cause of the problem.